# NSManagedObject shared properties

Tags: ios

I have just set up a simple Core Data database, and I have created a few entities with some properties. However some entities have some properties in common, like the Date parameter. Until now I do something like:

```
NSManagedObject * passedObject...

if ([_passedObject.entity.name isEqual:@"Archive"]){
    Archive* fileObject = (Archive *)_passedObject;
    myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:fileObject.fileData];
}else{
    AllFiles* fileObject = (AllFiles *)_passedObject;
    myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:fileObject.fileData];
}
```

fileData is common to both, so I would like just to be doing passedObject.fileData instead of casting the types. Can this be done?

Comment: Inheritance sounds like a potential option, although the way Core Data handles inheritance in a data model is fairly inelegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define a protocol...

```
@protocol FileDataProvider

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSData* fileData;

//or -(NSData *)fileData; would be suitable for RO access

@end
```

and make your objects  conform to that protocol

```
@interface Archive:NSManagedObject< FileDataProvider >

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSData* fileData;

@end


@interface AllFiles:NSManagedObject< FileDataProvider >

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSData* fileData;

@end
```

thus you can cast like so

```
myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:((id<FileDataProvider>)passedObject).fileData];
```

or safer

```
if([passedObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(FileDataProvider)]) {
    myDictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:((id<FileDataProvider>)passedObject).fileData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works great!! I actually declare my properties in this way: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * fileData; ..instead of using string, nonatomic. Would it still be ok?

Comment: Modern ARC property conventions are generally `strong` rather than `retain` (and `weak` rather than `assign` , mostly) . The actual declaration is unimportant with respect to the answer. Match the protocol and the class which implements is the only rule. so if protocol declares @property (bleep,bloop) AClass* thing; your implementing class much match it.